# Using Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB) in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ide, multithreading, tbb

I want to use Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB) in Linux. Can anyone suggest a good IDE for that and possibly any steps to integrate TBB with that IDE?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I know TBB is a set of C++ libraries which purpose to handle task of parallelization of code. So there is no need in any integration(exactly as you using STL) and you can use whatever IDE you wish, e.i. Eclipse, KDevelop and more.

Answer (score 0):

TBB is just a library, you can use it along with any C++ IDE. All you need to do is to set the include directory for the TBB installation.